# Mysql ERROR : not connected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to MySQL database from MySQL shell on windows.

No matter what I type in MySQL shell, it keeps giving me error : 'Not connected'.

Query eg 1 : `mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root -p;`

Query eg 2 : `mysql -u root -p`

O/P : `ERROR: Not connected`

I have MySQL server installed on my machine. Also MySQL service is running in the background.

Also, I was able to connect from MySQL workbench.

[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6sKc.png)

[MySQL Workbench Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo2rA.png)

Comment: Tip: it is more helpful to reader of the question if you copy the text into your post then to post as an image.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

My temporary workaround is that I make use of ssl protocol to connect to MySQL server :

MySQL> `\connect root@localhost`

MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  SQL > `show databases;`

Answer (score 19):

The first step is that you need to check if you are in the MYSQL Shell **SQL** mode or **JS** mode.

Then if you are in **SQL** mode then you are good to go else you need to switch to **SQL** mode by this command

`\sql`

The next step is to **connect** using this command

`\connect root@localhost`

In your case, you might have given the privilege as the IP address so you need to check your localhost IP which can be done by this command in your command prompt.

`ipconfig` and then just check the IP address and put it in place of localhost in the previous command. If this still doesn't works then put `127.0.0.1:3306`.

After this, it will prompt to add or save the password , enter a unique password there.

After this you are good to go and check the user and localhost after this by this command

`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;`

Comment: Once it shows the list of databases you can choose one DB =>
USE database_name;

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same issue on my Windows 10 machine with MySQL 5.7 and the following commands helped me:

`mysqlsh.exe` - to open mysql shell; then

`\sql` - to start working with SQL;

finally:

`\connect root@127.0.0.1:3306`

Answer (score 3):

Try `mysql -u root -p`
I haven't used MySQL shell, I typically use gitbash and it works just fine

Comment: Exactly. I tried that earlier in cmd and it works there. But it still doesn't work in MySQL shell. And I had like to make it work in MySQL shell.

Comment: I have a PATH variable set which points to "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mysql -uroot -hlocalhost -P3306 -p
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -p
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: Tried all 3 commands in shell and it keeps producing same error message : 'Not Connected'

Comment: Can you re-verify your port once, by using :  mysqladmin variables -u root -p